# Typescript : Property 'data' dose not exist on type HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try to get all elemets which have a class name in typescript and need to check something on data property of each element, this is what I came so far :

```
let getTopElements :NodeListOf<HTMLElement>  = document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-row');
var newArr: HTMLElement[] = Array.prototype.slice.call(getTopElements);

if (getTopElements){
  for (let element of newArr){
    if (element.data('options') && element.data('options').type === 'TOP')   {
       this.player.currentTime(element.data('options').end).pause();
     }
   }
 }
```

But in my if condition line, I get this error on data `Property 'data' dose not exist on type HTMLElement`

Am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Because `data()` is a method from jQuery to get data attributes. You should use the `dataset` property to modify and read data attributes. Also keep in mind that you can only store **string** values in a data attribute:

```
 const data = element.dataset;
 data.optionsType = 'TOP';
 if (data.optionsType === 'TOP')   {
   this.player.currentTime(data.optionsEnd).pause();
 }
```

Another option would be to use `getAttribute('data-*')` to get the value or `setAttribute('data-*', value)` to set the value.

You could have a look at the [**MDN page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for a tutorial how to properly use data attributes.